# How to make a Hosted Network with the hlep of C++

Tags: c++

Hy Guys! I want to make a program that boost or send your wifi signals to another computer. I'm going to use "netsh wlan" command in C++. But one thing i want is that ... i want to run a command of CMD is "netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=example key=example" in C++ but i want to Input ssid and key of hostednetwork form a user. I need all of you to solve this error. This a image that occurs a error...

[image]

Comment: Hlep? You might not be getting much hlep with that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: so, what i do bro?

Comment: i just want input ssid and key from a user!

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in C++.  You're better off using a command script.

Comment: What type of command script?

Comment: @FahadSaleem There's only one type: a file with a `.cmd` extension that contains a list of commands to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system()` takes a C-style string `char*` but you're trying to pass a `string`. To fix, create a temporary string something like this and convert it into a C-style string:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a;
    string b;
    cout << "Wifi Name : ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Password : ";
    cin >> b;

    string str = "netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=";
    str += a;
    str += " key=";
    str += b;
    system( str.c_str() );
    system("control.exe /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter");          
    cout<<"Press Enter for Menu...";
}
```

Comment: Can you fix my code and send to me again? Than i can understand well!

Comment: @FahadSaleem You posted the code as an image so it's hard to help you. If you post it as text it's easier to fix.

Comment: `#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
  string a;
  string b;
  cout<<"Wifi Name : ";
  cin>>a;
  cout<<"Password : ";
  cin>>b;
  system("netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=" + a + " key="+b);
  system("control.exe /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter");
  cout<<"Press Enter for Menu...";
 }`